How to use a mask as scale input for Instance on Points node?
I'm trying to scale my scattered instances according to a mask with falloff (white is scale of 1, black is scale of 0, then it blends out as a smooth gradient) but it does not work when plugged into the scale input on the Instance on Points node. It does work if I have the map info as a weight map, referenced in via string and named attribute, but I don't want to have to use a manual weight map, my goal is to have it use the procedural map with relevant input controls.
What is the best way to have a mask function as a scale input here?

Can you post a screenshot?
